# Any way to enable user_xattr on tmpfs?

Tags: cache, cifs, tmpfs

I am trying to cache CIFS share files on a ramdisk with `cachefilesd`, however `cachefilesd` requires the cache directory filesystem to support `user_xattr`. `tmpfs` does not by default. Is there any way to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Support for extended attributes was added to `tmpfs` [in 2011](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b09e0fa4b4ea66266058eead43350bd7d55fec67), but without support for user extended attributes. The latter was [recently enabled](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2daf18a7884dc03d5164ab9c7dc3f2ea70638469), so to get support for user extended attributes, you need a 6.6 kernel or later, with [`TMPFS_XATTR`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.9/source/fs/Kconfig#L205) enabled.

Comment: I have installed the latest stable Linux kernel version 6.6.9 configured with `CONFIG_TMPFS_XATTR=y`
`CONFIG_CIFS_XATTR=y`
and in `/etc/fstab` I have `tmpfs   /mnt/cache_tmpfs   tmpfs   defaults,size=58G,user_xattr   0   0` but I still get in `dmesg` an error [`tmpfs: Unknown parameter 'user_xattr'`](https://imgur.com/a/y4E6HgG). `uname -mrs` gives _Linux 6.6.9 x86_64_.

Comment: User attributes are enabled by default on file systems which support them, you mustn’t use a mount option. To check whether they work, you need to try actually using them, using `setfattr` for example.